# Show this is complete.

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and let $S$ be the set of Cauchy sequences in $S$. Define "~" in $X$ by declaring "$\{s_k\}$ ~ $\{t_k\}$" to mean that $d(s_k,t_k) \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$. Let $X'$ denote the set of equivalence classes of $S$ and let $s'$ denote the equivalence class of $s = {s_k}.

I showed that $\phi(s',t') = \lim\limits_{k \to \infty} d(s_k,t_k)$ is a metric on $X'$.

Now I need to show $(X',\phi)$ is complete. Then for $x \in X$, define $x'$ to be the equivalence class of the constant sequence ${x,x,...}$. Show that the function $x \to x'$ is an isometry of X onto a dense subset of X.

I don't even know where to start. I need to show for the second case that for any $y' \in X'$, we can find a sequence that converges to $y'$. Any help please?

Comment: For the second part, your $y'$ is an equivalence class of sequences from $X$. Try using one of those sequences.

Comment: For the first part you have to show the following: (a) For $x,y\in X$ you have $\phi(x',y') = d(x,y)$ (this is trivial); (b) For any $s'\in X'$ and any $\epsilon > 0$ you can find an $x\in X$ such that $\phi(s',x') < \epsilon$.

Comment: I thought of picking a $y' \in X$ and then considering $\{y'_k\}$, but I don't know where to go from there. @Adreas Blass